# mod_rewrite [L] flag not working as expected?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I thought the [L] flag indicated that "this rule should be the last rule processed for this http request.."

However when I have 2 rules like:

```
RewriteRule ^test$ php/test.php [L]
RewriteRule (.*) error.php
```

What always happens is requests to http://localhost/test go to error.php, **not** to test.php as I expected, since I put the [L] there.  If you comment out the second rule there, then requests to http://localhost/test go to test.php as expected.

What I'm really trying to do is catch 404 errors with mod_rewrite.  Its possible what I'm trying to do is just plain wrong.  But I still want to know why the catch-all rule is active since ***I did*** put an [L] after the `^test` rule.

I see a large listing in [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/rewriteguide.html) where the server admin lists a bunch of paths that begin with the recognized directories, but I wanted to avoid doing this by simply using a nice catch-all rule.

Comment: If you comment out *both* rules, where does `http://localhost/test` end up?

Answer (score 2):

If a rule results in a client redirect then it will re-enter the rule list again from the top when the client makes the redirected request.